# Parsing a WSDL with included XSDs that reference each other

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I am trying to use [suds version 0.4](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) with python version 2.7.1 to access a soap api, but I'm getting errors trying to create the [Client](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Client-class.html) object.  The simplest form is this:

```
from suds.client import Client

url = 'http://tool-sb-api.hescloud.net/session/wsdl'
c = Client(url, cache=None)
```

The error that is produced is:

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(retrieveSessionByIdResponse, http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session, )'
```

I've tried a few variations using [ImportDoctor](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.xsd.doctor.ImportDoctor-class.html) as per the [documented](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs) approaches, but I get the same error.

Upon inspecting the WSDL and the debug messages from suds, it seems to have a list of includes

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="HesAPI_Session" targetNamespace="http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session">
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="http://tool-sb-api.hescloud.net/public/xsd/session/input/newSessionFromAddress.xsd"/>
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="http://tool-sb-api.hescloud.net/public/xsd/session/output/newSessionFromAddressResponse.xsd"/>
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="http://tool-sb-api.hescloud.net/public/xsd/session/input/newLabelSession.xsd"/>
            ...
```

which reference each other.  Here is an example xsd which does this ([newSessionFromAddressResponse.xsd](http://tool-sb-api.hescloud.net/public/xsd/session/output/newSessionFromAddressResponse.xsd)).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://hes.lbl.gov/scoring_tool/session">
    <xsd:element name="newSessionFromAddressResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="returnCode" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="returnComment" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="readOnly" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element ref="tns:AddressList"/>

        <!-- RetrieveSessionByIdResponse is defined in retrieveSessionByIdResponse.xsd. In the event of an error, we won't have a retrieveSessionByIdResponse, hence minOccurs=0 -->
        <xsd:element ref="tns:retrieveSessionByIdResponse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="AddressList">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="zipcode" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

It seems suds is having issues with

```
<xsd:element ref="tns:retrieveSessionByIdResponse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

being defined in a different file.

I'm not sure if this WSDL follows [WSI-BP 1.0](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html) as the managers of this API claim or if the issue is with suds not being able to properly handle the "ref" attribute.

Either way, I'd be happy with a successfully created suds Client object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a [DocumentPlugin](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.plugin.DocumentPlugin-class.html) in order to load the contents of the xsd files directly into the document before it was parsed.

I had to override the [loaded](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.plugin.DocumentPlugin-class.html#loaded) function and do it using [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) (though any xml library would work).  I could not override the `parsed` function because I could not easily create a suds [Element](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.sax.element.Element-class.html) (it requires an `options` variable which contained information which was probably out of scope).

suds documents the creation of a DocumentPlugin [here](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#DocumentPlugin).

Comment: @Jorge Sorry, this was awhile back.  I don't think that code exists any longer :)